# For each array modification

Tags: php, arrays

I have this following code:

> ```
> foreach ($animals as $animal) {
>     $animal = getOffSpring($animal);
> }
> ```

Since I am setting $animal to a new string, will I be modifying the array as well please?

My run suggests that my array remains the same, but I want it to be modified with the new value. Is this the bug?

In other words, I want all the animals within my array to be modified to their offsprings

Comment: No. You must rewrite the value in array by an index at which it is present.

Comment: `array_map('getOffSpring', $animals)` will do the thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a reference:

```
foreach ($animals as &$animal) {
    $animal = getOffSpring($animal);
}
unset($animal);
```

The `unset` after the loop clears the reference. Otherwise you keep a reference to the last array element in `$animal` after the loop which will cause annoying problems if you forget about this and then use `$animal` later for something else.

Another option would be using the key to replace it:

```
foreach ($animals as $key => $animal) {
    $animals[$key] = getOffSpring($animal);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are trying to do that.
When you take `$animal` variable and pass it to a function or modifie it inside `foreach` loop, you work with independent variable, that isn't linked to `$animals` array in any way ( if you don't link it yourself ), therefore all changes applied to it, don't result in modification of `$animals` array.

```
foreach ( $animals as $i => $animal )
{
    $animals[ $i ] = getOffSpring( $animal );
}
```

As @AlecTMH mentioned in his comment, [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is also a solution.

```
array_map( 'getOffSpring', $animals );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference to the value in the array

```
foreach ($animals as &$animal) {
    $animal = getOffSpring($animal);
}
```